# uwsgi error bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 769]

Tags: django, uwsgi

Setting up django to use uwsgi I can run it using the command `uwsgi --ini kb_uwsgi.ini --http :8000` outside the virtualenv however trying to run the emperor command `sudo uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www-data --gid www-data` brings an error:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-16-133:/etc/uwsgi/vassals$ ls
kb_uwsgi.ini
ubuntu@ip-172-31-16-133:/etc/uwsgi/vassals$ sudo uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www-data --gid www-data
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.14 (64bit) on [Mon Jan 30 10:28:11 2017] ***
compiled with version: 5.4.0 20160609 on 06 January 2017 11:55:37
os: Linux-4.4.0-53-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:59:10 UTC 2016
nodename: ip-172-31-16-133
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/vassals
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
setgid() to 33
setuid() to 33
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 64137
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
*** starting uWSGI Emperor ***
*** has_emperor mode detected (fd: 6) ***
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from kb_uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.14 (64bit) on [Mon Jan 30 10:28:11 2017] ***
compiled with version: 5.4.0 20160609 on 06 January 2017 11:55:37
os: Linux-4.4.0-53-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:59:10 UTC 2016
nodename: ip-172-31-16-133
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/vassals
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
chdir() to /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz
your processes number limit is 64137
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 769]
Mon Jan 30 10:28:11 2017 - [emperor] curse the uwsgi instance kb_uwsgi.ini (pid: 25612)
Mon Jan 30 10:28:14 2017 - [emperor] removed uwsgi instance kb_uwsgi.ini
*** has_emperor mode detected (fd: 6) ***
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from kb_uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.14 (64bit) on [Mon Jan 30 10:28:16 2017] ***
compiled with version: 5.4.0 20160609 on 06 January 2017 11:55:37
os: Linux-4.4.0-53-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:59:10 UTC 2016
nodename: ip-172-31-16-133
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/vassals
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
chdir() to /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz
your processes number limit is 64137
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 769]
Mon Jan 30 10:28:16 2017 - [emperor] curse the uwsgi instance kb_uwsgi.ini (pid: 25613)
Mon Jan 30 10:28:19 2017 - [emperor] removed uwsgi instance kb_uwsgi.ini
*** has_emperor mode detected (fd: 6) ***
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from kb_uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.14 (64bit) on [Mon Jan 30 10:28:22 2017] ***
compiled with version: 5.4.0 20160609 on 06 January 2017 11:55:37
os: Linux-4.4.0-53-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:59:10 UTC 2016
nodename: ip-172-31-16-133
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/vassals
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
chdir() to /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz
your processes number limit is 64137
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 769]
Mon Jan 30 10:28:22 2017 - [emperor] curse the uwsgi instance kb_uwsgi.ini (pid: 25614)
^C[emperor] *** RAGNAROK EVOKED ***
Mon Jan 30 10:28:25 2017 - [emperor] removed uwsgi instance kb_uwsgi.ini
Mon Jan 30 10:28:25 2017 - [emperor] unloyal bad behaving vassal found: kb_uwsgi.ini throttling it...
Mon Jan 30 10:28:25 2017 - The Emperor is buried.
```

Here's the uwsgi file

```
# kb_uwsgi.ini file
[uwsgi]

http = :80
# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir           = /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz
# Django's wsgi file
module          = kb.wsgi
# the virtualenv (full path)
home            = /home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv

# process-related settings
# master
master          = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 10
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = /tmp/kb.sock
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket    = 664

# clear environment on exit
#vacuum          = true
```

Answer (score 0):

In the uwsgi file http port 80 is configured. By default, normal users are not allowed to bind to this port. That is why you are getting `bind(): Permission denied`. You can either [give permission](https://superuser.com/questions/710253/allow-non-root-process-to-bind-to-port-80-and-443) to the www-data user to use that port or use a different port.